# How to improve my XML design so it will look better

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Right know I have two designs of my android app, but it is annoying me that the buttons are not perfectly alligned. First of all I used 3 layers of Linear Layout, but my Enter button does not look good.

Then I decided to use Relative Layout, but the problem here is that middle buttons becomes bigger than its neighbors. Even thought my Enter button looks good I can not properly fit my button #3 and button #1. I tried to make Clear button

```
layout_toEndOf = button #1
```

But my whole design is disappearing after this.

I will be appreciate with any advice or tips!!!

**Linear Layout Design:**

[image: Linear Layout design]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/layerOne"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/result"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layerOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/layerTwo">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonZero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pressedZero"
            android:text="@string/_0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pressedOne"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:onClick="pressedClear"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layerTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/layerThree">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/_2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pressedTwo"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/_3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pressedThree"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/plus"
            android:onClick="pressedPlus"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layerThree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEnter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/enter"
            android:onClick="pressedEnter"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonStar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/star"
            android:onClick="pressedStar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Relative Layout Design**

[image: Relative Layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/result" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonZero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonTwo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:onClick="pressedZero"
        android:text="@string/_0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonEnter"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:onClick="pressedTwo"
        android:text="@string/_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:onClick="pressedClear"
        android:text="@string/clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonEnter"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/buttonTwo"
        android:onClick="pressedThree"
        android:text="@string/_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonThree"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/buttonZero"
        android:onClick="pressedOne"
        android:text="@string/_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonStar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:onClick="pressedPlus"
        android:text="@string/plus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:onClick="pressedStar"
        android:text="@string/star" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonStar"
        android:onClick="pressedEnter"
        android:text="@string/enter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In the future, ask the question as "how do I make these buttons align".  Look better is subjective and would be off topic, make them align is answerable.

Comment: I'd really recommend using ``ConstraintLayout`` and getting the hang of that. It's possible to do what you're doing by nesting other kinds of layouts, but it can be hard to work with, especially if you want to try different ideas out or make your layout look good on different screen sizes. You can easily do things like distributing buttons across available space, sizing them relative to each other etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is using `wrap_content` for the button widths alongside `layout_weight`. The layout weight will allocate all *extra* space to the buttons, so by starting with `wrap_content` you affect that calculation of "extra" space: the word "Enter" takes up more space than the number "0", so you have *less* space left over to distribute around.

Change all of your `layout_width="wrap_content"` attributes to `layout_width="0dp"` (wherever you're using `layout_weight`). That will ensure that the text contents of the buttons don't affect their final widths.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first two to have 3 equally sized buttons-  set the layout_width to 0dp and set the layout_weight to 1.  That will make the LinearLayout divide it into 3 evenly sized pieces.

For the bottom row, set the layout_width to 0dp and the layout_weight to 2 on the first button and 1 on the second.  That will make the first layout take twice the amount of space as the second, making it equal to the 2 buttons above.